# react-naitve xcode build main.jsbundle no such file error after watchman lost connected log

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, watchman

I am using `Xcode 12.4(12D4e)` `React-native(0.64)` `macOS BigSur` and would like to  release build  from Xcode.
But failed..
It says  xcode...

```
Release-iphoneos/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image]
it can't be found in.

But I made a main.jsbundle and added it to the project.
[image]

i using `script`

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets
```

I don't understand it here. During development, it worked without adding the script. However, the `release` build outputs that error.

I searched through various documents and tried. Then I found out. As the build runs through Xcode, the `metro server` is turned on, and the log is output and the `mainjsbundle` is not found.
[image]

I think this is a problem with the Watheman. I know the issue related to Big Sum m1 react-native and I'm building it using rosseta.
Could you give me a way to solve the problem if I missed something?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. DId you resolve it?

Comment: @gwalshington yes, resolve it. It was solved by modifying the script when building project in xcode